# How can I query a table for transitive matches?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Giving the following tables

#### Units:

```
| id | singular | plural |
|----|----------|--------|
| 3  | onion    | onions |
| 4  | bag      | bags   |
| 5  | gram     | grams  |
| 6  | ml       | ml     |
| 7  | mm       | mm     |
```

and

#### Conversions:

```
| id | convert_from | convert_to | factor |
|----|--------------|------------|--------|
| 3  | 4            | 3          | 5      |
| 4  | 3            | 5          | 125    |
```

How could I obtain all possible conversion factors from (for example) `bag` (unit `4`)?

I would expect the answers to resemble the form

```
| convert_from | convert_to | factor |
|--------------|------------|--------|
| 4            | 3          | 5      |
| 4            | 5          | 625    |
```

### Caveats:

1. There is no guarantee about which column of the conversions table (`convert_from`, `convert_to`) a unit might appear in.
2. Conversions that transit through units `5`, `6`, or `7` should be ignored.

   That is to say,
   `1->2->4->5` is valid, `1->2->4->5->7` is not.
3. A `SQL` solution (or re-architecting of the database to facilitate a SQL solution) would be ideal, but a code solution that makes multiple SQL queries would also be appreciated.
4. There will be other units in the units table that should be ignored if they do not form part of the conversion graph (or if they form part of the branch through an invalid transition (`5`, `6`, or `7`)). This is a simplified view.

### Illustrative example

Ignoring SQL and retrieving the data for a moment, here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I want to build a system where users can store household products. A product has a unit associated with it. The unit might be an SI unit, such as mm, ml, g.. or it might be a discrete unit such as onion, or can.

Units can have relationships amongst themselves, so for example `1 can -> 330 ml`.
The complexity of my question comes from the fact that the conversions for a single unit might be spread across many products.

Considering the `can` example again, we can have a product called `pepsi (crate of 24)` with the unit being `crate`, and another product called `pepsi (can)` with the unit of `can`.

When the user creates the `pepsi (can)` product, they provide the following conversion:

```
1 can -> 330 ml
```

Later, the user creates the `pepsi (crate of 24)` product, and provides the following conversion:

```
1 crate -> 24 can
```

Finally, the user asks the question "how much pepsi do I have?"

I'd like to be able to answer:

- 25 cans
- 1.0417 crates
- 8250 ml.

However, I don't know how to convert crates to ml.

Here's another example in illustrated form:

[image: illustrated example of onion conversions.]

### Edit:

1. Changed mms and mls to mm and ml. Not sure what I was thinking...
2. Added diagram to help clarify *what i'm looking for* rather than the solution.

Comment: The plural of ml is ml, and the plural of mm is mm. Just sayin'

Comment: What's so special about 5, 6, 7? It seems they are "terminal units". Is there any mark on them? Thinking that in the future there may be more "special units"...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE, assuming there are no cycles in the data.

I added an extra `is_terminal` column to identify the terminal units where you don't want to convert from anymore (5, 6, and 7). The query is:

```
with recursive
e (convert_from, convert_to, factor, is_terminal) as (
  select id, id, 1, is_terminal from units where id = 4 -- bag
 union all
  select e.convert_from, c.convert_to, e.factor * c.factor, u.is_terminal
  from e
  join conversions c on c.convert_from = e.convert_to
  join units u on u.id = c.convert_to
  where not e.is_terminal
)
select * from e where convert_from <> convert_to
```

Result:

```
convert_from  convert_to  factor  is_terminal
------------  ----------  ------  -----------
4             3           5       false
4             5           625     true
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oyR1vQPDGbokyN71zUcYaE/0) . Here's the data script I used to test:

```
create table units (
  id int,
  is_terminal boolean
);

insert into units (id, is_terminal) values
  (3, false), (4, false),
  (5, true), (6, true), (7, true);

create table conversions (
  id int,
  convert_from int,
  convert_to int,
  factor int
);

insert into conversions (id, convert_from, convert_to, factor) values
  (3, 4, 3, 5),
  (4, 3, 5, 125);
```

Comment: Hey, this looks great. Let me give it a test and then I'll mark it as the answer. You're right about the is_terminal column I do have one!

Comment: So this does work, but not in every case. It works great when you start from a unit that sits at the start of a chain (eg. 4->3->5, and you start with 4). 

However, if you start with 3, you miss out on the 3->4 relationship.

Comment: I thought about adding all the conversions twice, in each direction (4->3 ; 3->4) but that causes as infinite loop as you pointed out...